# Why can't we provide implicit typeclass when a type is covariant?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, typeclass, scalaz, scala-cats

I'm designing my algebraic data type and faced a problem of unabling to provide implicit typeclass. Here is what I have:

```
sealed abstract class Stream[+F[_], +T] {
  def run()(implicit M: Monad[F]): F[Unit] = Stream.run(this)
}

object Stream{
  final case object Halt extends Stream[Nothing, Nothing]
  private def run[F[_], T](stream: Stream[F, T])(implicit M: Monad[F]): F[Unit] = stream match {
    case Halt => M.pure()
  }
}
```

I got the compile error

```
Error:(10, 22) covariant type F occurs in invariant position in type 
     Monad[F] of value M def run()(implicit M: Monad[F]): F[Unit] = M.pure()
```

I made it covariant in order to be able to return `Halt extends Stream[Nothing, Nothing]` without casting but yet I need `Monad[F]` typeclass in order to  use its operation for a context `F[_]` provided. What would be a solution in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would only compile if `Monad` were *contra*-variant. Otherwise you have:

```
val stream: Stream[Nothing, Nothing] = Halt
val stream1: Stream[Maybe, Int] = stream // by covariance
val x = stream1.run()(implicitly[Monad[Maybe]])
```

but `Halt.run` only accepts a `Monad[Nothing]`, so `Monad[Maybe]` must be a subtype of `Monad[Nothing]`.

> What would be a solution in this case?

Not to define `run` like this? Generally, because scalaz and cats decided to make their typeclasses invariant, you'll run into trouble when trying to use them in co/contravariant types.